# JavaCV and parameters installation

Tags: eclipse, opencv, netbeans, jna, javacv

After many research on internet about install JavaCV in Eclipse or Net Beans. I write this text because i do not found how fix my problem.

---

- Java SE Developement kit update 10 ( I use JDK 1.7 )
- OpenCV 2.4.2 (in c:\ )
- JavaCV 0.2 bin (in c:\ )
- JNA 3.4.0 (C:\javacv-bin\JNA)
- Windows 7 32 bits.
- Eclips IDE for Java Developers 32 bits.
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) installed

---

I created a new project in Eclipse.

1. I added in environement variables: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin; C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10
2. Added all external library
3. I fixed dependency problems with depends.exe and added "IEShims.dll" because missing.

---

And now when i launch my program i have always his errors.

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\SweetLive\AppData\Local\Temp\jniopencv_core3957460997136742229.dll:
> >     Can't find dependent libraries    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)     at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)  at
> >     java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)     at
> >     java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:403)    at
> >     com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:342)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:316)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.(opencv_core.java:131)
> >       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
> >     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
> >       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
> >     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.(opencv_objdetect.java:96)
> >       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
> >     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:316)   at
> >     com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect$CvHaarClassifierCascade.>(opencv_objdetect.java:175)   at DetectVisage.main(DetectVisage.java:50)

For all this, i used:
http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/Windows7AndOpenCV
http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs10/install/javacv-win/

And i can't see on blogspot because this website blocked in China (I'm foreign student in China)

Someone has an idea to solve my problem? thanx in advance.

Comment: `jniopencv_core3957460997136742229.dll` appears to be a temporary library used by openCV.  Any libraries on which it depends must be located in either the same directory or found on `PATH`.

Comment: Yes, i know. Normal step 1 with environment is directory add for this library, for the PATH. Maybe link between javacv and opencv is bad ? how i can know ?

Comment: Have you tried with JavaCV 0.3 and OpenCV 2.4.3?